# Merging multiple reports and assigning it to ReportSource of XRSubReport

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtrareport

This code gives me proper output. I can see the subReport inside my vpReport.
But,

```
    private void createReport(List<DataSet> dataList> 
    {
      ENG.Report vpReport = new UI.ENG.Report();
    
      ENG.SubReport subReport = new ENG.SubReport();
      subReport.DataSource = dataList[0];
      (vpReport.FindControl("xrSubReport1", true) as XRSubreport).ReportSource = subReport;
      vpReport.ShowPreview();
    }
```

This code just gives me blank in place of xrSubReport1. I don't understand why. I tried setting margin lesser than vpReport too. I tried adding pages directly to vpReport. Nothing works. How do I achieve this. I need to merge all the subReport i have, and add that to my main report vpReport.

```
private void createReport(List<DataSet dataList) 
{
  ENG.Report vpReport = new UI.ENG.Report();
  XtraReport mergedReport = new XtraReport();
  foreach (DataSet ds in dataList)
  {
     ENG.SubReport subReport = new ENG.SubReport();
     subReport.DataSource = ds;
     subReport.CreateDocument();
     mergedReport.Pages.AddRange(subReport.Pages);
  }
  (vpreport.FindControl("xrSubReport1", true) as XRSubreport).ReportSource = mergedReport;
  vpReport.ShowPreview();
}
```

Please guide me

Comment: If you are using the DataSet as a report's data source, make sure that the `subReport.DataMember` property is set correctly, i.e., that it references the required table in the DataSet. 

Also, for debugging purposes, call the `XtraReport.ShowDesigner` method at runtime: this will open the End-User Report Designer where you can play with subreport properties and switch back and forth to designer/preview.